# Java - Convert a HEX color to a decimal color

Tags: java, colors, hex, decimal

I want to convert a HEX color (Like #FF0000) to a decimal color (Like 16711680). How do I need to do this?

I've already tried using the Color class, but I can't find a method for converting the colors correctly.

```java
Color hexcolor = Color.decode("#FF0000");
//And then?
```

Comment: FF0000 in hexadecimal is 16711680 in decimal, so you treat the "color" just like any other number.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I think I can find something then. I didn't know that it was that simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way validating input could be:

```java
public static int parseHex(final String color) {
    final Matcher mx = Pattern.compile("^#([0-9a-z]{6})$", CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(color);
    if(!mx.find())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid color value");
    return Integer.parseInt(mx.group(1), 16);
}
```

Although not required, you can parse each color component separately:

```java
public static int parseColor(final String color) {
    final Matcher mx = Pattern.compile("^#([0-9a-z]{2})([0-9a-z]{2})([0-9a-z]{2})$", CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(color);
    if(!mx.find())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid color value");
    final int R = Integer.parseInt(mx.group(1), 16);
    final int G = Integer.parseInt(mx.group(2), 16);
    final int B = Integer.parseInt(mx.group(3), 16);
    return (R << 16) + (G << 8) + B;
}
```

If depend of `Color` is not a problem, you can use:

```java
public static int parseColor(final String color) {
    final Color c = Color.decode(color);
    return (c.getRed() << 16) + (c.getGreen() << 8) + c.getBlue();
}
```

On the other way, you can do too:

```java
public static int parseColor(final String color) {
    return 0xFFFFFF & (Color.decode(color).getRGB() >> 8);
}
```

But since require to know the internal representation, this is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I've already found a anwser because of the comment of vlumi.

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-hex-to-decimal

```java
public static int convertHEXtoDecimal(String HEX) {
    String hex = HEX.replaceAll("#", "");
    String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    hex = hex.toUpperCase();
    int val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++) {
        char c = hex.charAt(i);
        int d = digits.indexOf(c);
        val = 16 * val + d;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Looks better use `Integer.parseInt` instead.